# Improving sort performance in GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, group-by, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

I have two tables in Postgres 9.4.1 `events` and `event_refs` with the following schemas:

**`events` table**

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  event_type text NOT NULL,
  event_path jsonb,
  event_data jsonb,
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

-- Index on type and created time

CREATE INDEX events_event_type_created_at_idx
  ON events (event_type, created_at);
```

**`event_refs` table**

```
CREATE TABLE event_refs (
  event_id integer NOT NULL,
  reference_key text NOT NULL,
  reference_value text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT event_refs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (event_id, reference_key, reference_value),
  CONSTRAINT event_refs_event_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (event_id)
      REFERENCES events (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Both tables hold 2M rows. This is the query I'm running

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX(events.created_at) - MIN(events.created_at))) as funnel_time
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
  event_refs
ON
  event_refs.event_id = events.id AND
  event_refs.reference_key = 'project'
WHERE
    events.event_type = 'event1' OR
    events.event_type = 'event2' AND
    events.created_at >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00+08:00' AND
    events.created_at < '2015-12-01 00:00:00+08:00'
GROUP BY event_refs.reference_value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I am aware of the operator precedence in the where clause. It is only supposed to filter events with the type 'event2' by date.

This is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=116503.86..120940.20 rows=147878 width=14) (actual time=3970.530..4163.041 rows=53532 loops=1)
   Group Key: event_refs.reference_value
   Filter: (count(*) > 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 41315
   ->  Sort  (cost=116503.86..116873.56 rows=147878 width=14) (actual time=3970.509..4105.316 rows=153766 loops=1)
         Sort Key: event_refs.reference_value
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3904kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=24302.26..101275.04 rows=147878 width=14) (actual time=101.667..1394.281 rows=153766 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (event_refs.event_id = events.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on event_refs  (cost=0.00..37739.00 rows=2000000 width=10) (actual time=0.007..368.661 rows=2000000 loops=1)
                     Filter: (reference_key = 'project'::text)
               ->  Hash  (cost=21730.79..21730.79 rows=147878 width=12) (actual time=101.524..101.524 rows=153766 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 16384  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 3315kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=3761.23..21730.79 rows=147878 width=12) (actual time=23.139..75.814 rows=153766 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((event_type = 'event1'::text) OR ((event_type = 'event2'::text) AND (created_at >= '2015-07-01 04:00:00+12'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2015-12-01 05:00:00+13'::timestamp with time zone)))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=14911
                           ->  BitmapOr  (cost=3761.23..3761.23 rows=150328 width=0) (actual time=21.210..21.210 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_event_type_created_at_idx  (cost=0.00..2349.42 rows=102533 width=0) (actual time=12.234..12.234 rows=99864 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (event_type = 'event1'::text)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_event_type_created_at_idx  (cost=0.00..1337.87 rows=47795 width=0) (actual time=8.975..8.975 rows=53902 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((event_type = 'event2'::text) AND (created_at >= '2015-07-01 04:00:00+12'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2015-12-01 05:00:00+13'::timestamp with time zone))
 Planning time: 0.493 ms
 Execution time: 4178.517 ms
```

I am aware that the filter on the `event_refs` table scan is not filtering anything, that is a result my test data, there will be different types added later.

Everything under and including the `HashJoin` seems reasonable give my test data, but I'm wondering if it's possible to increase the `Sort` speed from the `GROUP BY` clause?

I've tried adding a b-tree index to the `reference_value` column but it doesn't seem to use it. If I'm not mistaken (and I very well could be so please tell me), it's sorting 153766 rows. Wouldn't an index be beneficial to this sorting process?

Comment: Your sort does seem to take bizarrely long.  What is your database collation set to? In psql, do `\l+`.

Comment: Also, what is your OS?  PostgreSQL out-sources the locale-dependent collation comparisons to your OS, so sort speed can depend on that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `work_mem`

That's what makes your sort expensive:

> Sort Method: external merge Disk: 3904kB

The sort spills to disk, which kills performance. You need more RAM. In particular, you need to increase the setting for **`work_mem`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM)

> `work_mem` (`integer`)
>
> Specifies the amount of memory to be used by internal sort operations
>   and hash tables before writing to temporary disk files.

In this particular case, raising the setting by a meager 4MB should do the trick. Generally, since you are going to need a lot more in your full deployment for 60M rows and since it can backfire if the general setting for `work_mem` is too high (read the manual where I linked to!), consider setting it high enough locally for your query, like:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL work_mem = '500MB';  -- adapt to your needs
SELECT ...;
COMMIT;
```

Be aware that even `SET LOCAL` sticks until the end of the transaction. You may want to reset if you put more into the same transaction:

```
RESET work_mem;
```

Or encapsulate the query in a function with a function-local setting. Related answer with example for function:

- [Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584053/939860)

#### Indexes

I would also try these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX events_event_type_created_at_idx ON events (event_type, created_at, id);
```

Adding `id` as last column only makes sense if you get **index-only scans** out of it. See:

- [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-index-only-scans.html)
- [The Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)

And a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) on `event_refs`:

```
CREATE INDEX event_refs_foo_idx ON event_refs (event_id, reference_value);
WHERE  reference_key = 'project';
```

The predicate `WHERE reference_key = 'project'` does not help much in your test case (except maybe for query planning), but it should help a lot in your full deployment where `there will be different types added later`.

And this should also allow index-only scans.

#### Possible alternative query

Since you are selecting large parts of `events` anyway, this alternative query *might* be faster (heavily depends on data distribution):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX(e.created_at) - MIN(e.created_at))) as funnel_time
FROM   events e
JOIN  (
   SELECT event_id, reference_value, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   event_refs
   WHERE  reference_key = 'project'                   
   GROUP  BY event_id, reference_value
   ) r ON r.event_id = e.id
WHERE (e.event_type = 'event1' OR
       e.event_type = 'event2')        -- see below !
AND    e.created_at >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00+08:00'
AND    e.created_at <  '2015-12-01 00:00:00+08:00'
GROUP  BY r.reference_value
HAVING sum(r.ct) > 1;
```

I *suspect* a bug in the query, and that you want parentheses in the `WHERE` clause like I added. According to [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), `AND` binds before `OR`.

Only makes sense if there are *many* rows per `(event_id, reference_value)` in `event_refs`. Again, the above index would help.

Comment: Thanks, changing work_mem took out the disk sort and decreased the total time to about 200ms. Will look through the rest of what you've posted.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Comment: @JamesHay: I know, this answer is old, but the new comment caught my attention. Note the added bit about operator precedence at the bottom.

Comment: is it possible to just `SET work_mem TO '1GB'` then query and then `RESET` ? Or is better using a transaction? Thanks