# How to optimize Merge Anti Join?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, explain

While trying to find the fastest way to do a bulk update of a large table, I came up with the following plan:

having `main_table` (potentially above 1000 mln rows) and `update` table up to a few million rows. Data in `update` are indexed according to `main_table` (have corresponding `id` columns).

1. copy rows from `main_table` into `temp_table` where `id` not in `update` `id` table  (where data has actually changed).
2. simple append of the `update` table onto `temp_table`
3. drop `main_table`
4. rename `temp_table` to `main_table`
5. renumerate `main_table` `pk`
6. create the next `update` with `python` and repeat.

The above is to be done with the following sequence of queries:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (like main_table including all);
INSERT INTO  temp_table (listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp)
    (SELECT listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp
         FROM   main_table c
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                            FROM   update
                            WHERE  id = c.id));
INSERT INTO temp_table (listing_id,date,available,price,parsing_timestamp)
    (SELECT listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp
     FROM   update c);
DROP  TABLE main_table cascade;
ALTER TABLE temp_table RENAME TO main_table;
ALTER TABLE main_table DROP COLUMN id
ALTER TABLE main_table ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
DROP  TABLE update cascade;
```

While debugging the queries, I have found the slow queries with `explain`:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) CREATE TABLE temp_table (like main_table including all);
INSERT INTO  temp_table (listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp)
    (SELECT listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp
         FROM   main_table c
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                            FROM   update
                            WHERE  id = c.id));
```

This is the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as requested in comments:

```
QUERY PLAN
Merge Anti Join (cost=513077.42..4789463.48 rows=109800833 width=40) (actual time=1216.018..48520.564 rows=112757269 loops=1)
Merge Cond: (c.id = update.id)
Buffers: shared hit=4 read=1359891 written=2838, temp read=8701 written=15077
-> Index Scan using cals_pkey on cals c (cost=0.57..3958576.01 rows=113119496 width=44) (actual time=0.857..29573.798 rows=113119497 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1330192 written=2838
 -> Sort (cost=513076.85..521373.51 rows=3318663 width=8) (actual time=1215.147..1260.191 rows=362229 loops=1)
Sort Key: update.id
Sort Method: external merge Disk: 58480kB
Buffers: shared hit=3 read=29699, temp read=8701 written=15077
-> Seq Scan on update (cost=0.00..62881.63 rows=3318663 width=8) (actual time=0.179..423.100 rows=3318663 loops=1)
Buffers: shared read=29695
Planning Time: 0.259 ms
Execution Time: 52757.349 ms
```

How to optimize the queries?

Comment: No, the INSERT is the last operation. You need to read the plan from the inside-out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, but how to avoid all that `Sort`s then?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Did you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)?` If not, could you please replace your plan with the result of that command?

Comment: @Vérace,  Hi, please find the edit above following to your comment

Comment: 50 seconds for 100 million rows seems pretty good.  Does it really need to be optimized?

Comment: You say `CREATE TABLE temp_table (like main_table including all);` So you should disclose the table definition to give the full picture. It's unclear why you need to drop and recreate the `id` column at the end. Do you *need* gapless numbers? Would your use case benefit from physically sorted rows after the `UPDATE` operation?

Comment: Also, why `parsing_timestamp` <> `timestamp`?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the sort performance in the query, there is this:

> ```
> Sort Method: external merge Disk: 58480kB
> ```

Meaning, there is not enough [**`work_mem`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) to sort in RAM. The operation spills to disk, which is typically *a lot* more expensive. If you have more RAM to spare, increase the setting for the current session (only!).

See:

- [Improving sort performance in GROUP BY clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125094/improving-sort-performance-in-group-by-clause/125155#125155)

Check with `SHOW work_mem;`, then add 100 MB to the number you get and use it below instead of `'???MB'`. If you still see mention of "disk" in the `EXPLAIN` output, add more.

But there is more: You create the new table with:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (like main_table including all);
```

`INCLUDING ALL`, as the wording suggests, also includes constraints and indexes. Obviously, at least a PK constraint as indicated by `cals_pkey` in the `EXPLAIN` output. I assume a column:

```
id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
```

It's **a lot cheaper** to create an index on a filled table than to update it incrementally. The index is also typically better optimized. So you should drop the PK (and all other indexes and constraints) before you write to the table, and recreate them afterwards.

Also, dropping and re-creating the `id` column on a huge table is needlessly expensive. Create new values for `id` on the fly with `row_number()` (do you really need to renumber?). Then update the associated `SEQUENCE` accordingly.

Related:

- [Copy table with separate sequences for serial columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/copy-table-with-separate-sequences-for-serial-columns/91658#91658)
- [How to copy structure and contents of a table, but with separate sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265248/939860)

Assuming ...

- you *need* to renumber all rows
- no concurrent load on the table
- `parsing_timestamp` is a typo in the question and should really be the same column `timestamp`. Else, adapt accordingly.

... the operation could look something like this:

```
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL work_mem = '???MB';  -- see above

CREATE TABLE temp_table (LIKE main_table INCLUDING ALL);

ALTER TABLE temp_table DROP CONSTRAINT temp_table_pkey;  -- before!
-- drop more indexes or constraints?

INSERT INTO temp_table 
      (id                  , listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp)
SELECT row_number() OVER (), listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp
FROM  (
   SELECT listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp  -- No parentheses around SELECT
   FROM   main_table c
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM update WHERE id = c.id);

   UNION ALL      
   SELECT listing_id,date,available,price,timestamp  -- parsing_timestamp ???
   FROM   update
   ) sub

DROP  TABLE main_table CASCADE;
DROP  TABLE update CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE temp_table RENAME TO main_table;
ALTER TABLE main_table ADD CONSTRAINT main_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);  -- after!
-- recreate more indexes or constraints?

SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('main_table', 'id'), max(id)) FROM main_table;  -- reset sequence

COMMIT;
```

Also, some more of the advice for ["Populating a Database" in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/populate.html) may well apply to your case. Maybe more `maintenance_work_mem`, maybe `ANALYZE` or `VACUUM ANALYZE` afterwards, ... Have a look.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, your method is in fact slightly faster, but it still would take a month to populate the database. With Python Pandas, which as I am  much more comfortable with, the problem is just a simple append and drop_duplicates. Is there any chance to find a faster solution?

Comment: it takes about 20 minutes to complete the query.

Comment: Maybe. Addressing my questions would be a start.